# Rooted Galaxy Note 3 randomly restarting

Tags: system-error

My Galaxy Note 3 recently started rebooting at random times, and I'm not sure where to start looking for the problem. I could start uninstalling apps and seeing if the problem goes away, but the restarts are usually hours or even days apart.
Is there some sort system log I should check for errors around the time of the reboot? Or any other suggestions for debugging my issue?
I apologize for the very vague problem, I just really need some advice on where to start.

Comment: Trouble is the logs don't survive the restart. So it's hard to check them when you don't know what time the reboot happens. First questions would be what you changed last before this started, e.g. some settings, or some new app(s) installed.

Comment: You could start by telling us which ROM you are running. Also, try to remember what you were doing at the time. CPU intensive activities such as games can affect the crash.

Comment: Custom ROMS, especially 4.4 based are very prone to this issue. I had the same on GS4 but it was due to smokes packet pressing the power button of all things! We'd need to know what you are running on the device, especially firmware.

Comment: I'm using a rooted stock ROM, and I doubt it's to do with CPU intensive actions as it's hasn't happened (yet) while I'm actively using the device, just while it's idle. I guess I'm going to have to start uninstalling apps...

Comment: If you enable adb and have your device connected to a computer at the time of reboot, you could get the logcat entries you'd need to start finding where the source of the problem is. [This tutorial](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2141817) can help you learn how to do that. Not the best, but definitely beats uninstalling apps one-by-one.